# Keep record even after deleting from application

Tags: asp.net

I have two tables, category (pk) and foreign key table Item(fk).

In item table have itemid, item name,category I'd....and this category I'd is foreign key column with primary table...which is having category I'd, Category name.

And I have relationship between category table as parent and. Item table as child table....category I'd is the relationship between them. When I delete records based on itemid the records should be deleted from the application but maintained at backed level..as I do not want duplicate item...even I have deleted from application.

At Application level I am doing these things with textboxes for and drop down list which should category names.

Answer (score 0):

If I have got you correctly, what you want to do is, maintain the data in the database table even if you delete it from the application interface.
If that is the case, you simply can add a column like 'isDeleted' in both of the tables in the database. In the delete event, just fire the update statement instead of actually deleting the record and set the 'isDeleted' field value to 'True'. At the time of displaying data from the tables, just select the records having 'isDeleted' value equals to 'False'.

Comment: I Have understood what you were explaining...also..my requirement is...the..records..should not be..duplicated...when i try to add...new record with the ..already present record(i.e the hidden or deleted record)....but the thing...is...which datatype...should be selected to Is..deleted column name....and can you briefly...show me with a small example..